# Pipes, Forks and Polls in parent-child process

Tags: c, fork, pipe, parent-child, polling

I am working on an assignment where I have to count the number of chars from the command line arguments. The parent is to pass the child one char at a time and the child is to count the number of chars and return the count to the parent so it can print the number of chars. When I run my program it just sits and does nothing. I think my problem is when I get to the stage of passing the count back to the parent and reaping the child. I think my code is fairly solid up until that point and then that is were I get a little fuzzy. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// Characters from command line arguments are sent to child process
// from parent process one at a time through pipe.
//
// Child process counts number of characters sent through pipe.
//
// Child process returns number of characters counted to parent process.
//
// Parent process prints number of characters counted by child process.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>        //for fork and pip
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   pid_t   pid;
   int     comm[2];
   int     status;
   char    src;

   // set up pipe
   if (pipe(comm))
   {
      printf("Pipe Error!\n");
      return -1;
   }

   // call fork()
   pid = fork();

   //check if fork failed
   if (pid < 0)
   {
      printf("Fork Error! %d\n", pid);
      return -1;
   }

   if (pid == 0) 
   {
         // -- running in child process --

        //close output side of pipe
        close(comm[1]);

        int     nChars = 0;
        printf("in child\n");

        // Receive characters from parent process via pipe
        // one at a time, and count them.

        while (read(comm[0], &src, 1))
        {
            ++nChars;
            printf("testing child loop = %d\n", nChars);
        }

        //close input side of pipe
        close(comm[0]);
        // Return number of characters counted to parent process.
        return nChars;
   }
   else 
   {
         // -- running in parent process --
        int     nChars = 0;

        //close input side of pipe
        close(comm[0]);

        printf("Assignment 3\n");

        // Send characters from command line arguments starting with
        // argv[1] one at a time through pipe to child process.
        int i;
        for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i) //loop through each argument
        {
            int j;
            for (j = 0; j < strlen(argv[i]); ++j)   //loop through each character in argument
                write(comm[1], &argv[i][j], 1);
        }

        //closing the write end of the pipe
        close(comm[1]);

        // Wait for child process to return. Reap child process.
        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
        // Receive number of characters counted via the value
        // returned when the child process is reaped

        printf("child counted %d chars\n", nChars);
        return 0;
    }
```

}

Comment: (1) You don't need to use poll for this.  You are making it more complicated than you have to.  Just have the parent close the write end of the pipe when it is done writing.  The child will get EOF.  (2) If you plan on returning the # of chars in the return code - not sure why I am seeing this horrible practice so often here the last couple of days - you need to interrogate the status code returned in `wait` to print the answer. (3) The parent is not magically going to print the answer from nChars - the child & parent have separate copies of memory.

Comment: For your immediate problem moving `close(comm[1]);` before the `wait` should do the job.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It is executing the print statement now but no matter how many args I enter at the command line it it says there are 0 chars.

Comment: See (3) above.  The child is incrementing nChars, not the parent.  Two separate copies of memory.  You have to use the return code in `wait` - if that was your intent- or pass the total back to the parent another way.

Comment: i guess that is where I am confused...I dont understand how to pass the nChars back to the parent. I also think there is something wrong with my while loop condition or the data isn't getting passed from the parent correctly. I did some print statements and the loop never gets envoked so nChars never actually gets incremented.

Comment: (1) You can, as seems to be your original plan, pass it back as the child's return code.  This is a terrible practice and only good if it is less than 255.  (2) Use some kind of IPC e.g. pipes, shared mem, etc.  "Hint": use a second pipe going in the other direction.  (3) Get rid of the `poll` stuff.  The child's read loop is literally two lines of code.

Comment: I took out the poll part of it and now my loop in the child process is working correctly and the count is right, but the nChars in the parent process is still not getting updated with the correct value from the nChars in the child process. The return nChars statement returns the value of nChars from the child to the parent, correct? Then how does the parent catch the value and store it into it's version of nChars. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: See `man (3) wait` and how to use the WEXITSTATUS macro.

Answer (score 0):

Here is basically how you *should* have done it - unless you were absolutely forced to go the return code route.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>

#define errExit(msg) do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)

#define c2p 0
#define p2c 1
#define READEND 0
#define WRITEEND 1

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   pid_t   pid;
   int     comm[2][2];
   char    src;

   for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
       if (pipe(comm[i]))
           errExit("pipe");

   if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
       errExit("fork");

   if (! pid)
   {
       close(comm[p2c][WRITEEND]);
       close(comm[c2p][READEND]);

       int nChars = 0;

       while (read(comm[p2c][READEND], &src, 1))
           ++nChars;

       write(comm[c2p][WRITEEND], &nChars, sizeof(nChars));

       close(comm[c2p][WRITEEND]);  //sends eof to parent

       printf("child counted %d chars\n", nChars);

       return 0;
   }

   int nChars = 0;

   close(comm[p2c][READEND]);
   close(comm[c2p][WRITEEND]);

   printf("Assignment 3\n");

   for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) //loop through each argument
   {
       int len = strlen(argv[i]);

       for (int j = 0; j < len; ++j)
           write(comm[p2c][WRITEEND], &argv[i][j], 1);
   }

   close(comm[p2c][WRITEEND]); //sends eof to child

   read(comm[c2p][READEND], &nChars, sizeof(nChars));  //should really be in a loop - your task

   close(comm[c2p][READEND]);

   wait(0);

   printf("parent reports %d chars\n", nChars);

   return 0;

}
```